# Can someone please explain the notation below?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have been trying to understand the notation for objective C
its using the CAP(^) character along with the functions.

Can someone please enlighten me with the fact what this means and what this is used for.

Thanks
Jay

EG: `^(void)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called "blocks", which are closures for Objective C.

More about closures in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

More about objective C blocks: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 5):

this notation is used for block in iOS.
You can check more details on - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html